# Create an OWIN OUath token from controller without using token/oauth request

Tags: c#, oauth

I have a server that is setup to use Owin / Oauth using the standard token/oauth endpoint, and does the user credential check (password / username).

However, we have a new workflow which requires me to manually create the OAuth token that the standard endpoint does, but from a different location in the code. I have access to the Request so can get the OwinContext, etc.

One way I think I can do this is to re-request the localhost with the token/oauth endpoint, adding in the correct values that I programmatically get in my new process. However, this seems hacky. Is there a way I can execute the Token generation from within a Controller?

Thanks,

Comment: Where are you doing this? ASP.NET? ASP.NET Core? Other?

Comment: hi @John we are using .net Framework 4.6

Comment: @user631845 It doesn’t really answer the question as ASP.NET Core is also available for .NET Framework (or rather all .NET Standard 2.0 or higher frameworks).

Comment: The application is developed on .Net Framework 4.6. We are hosting on Azure and using the standard WebApi Controller functionality. It looks like we are using Microsoft.AspNet . Do you have anything more specific I can look for?

Comment: `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` has methods under `AccessTokenFormat` and `RefreshTokenProvider` for creating access tokens and refresh tokens. It has been a long time since I did ASP.NET but I think you can manually create an `AuthenticationTicket`, protect it with `AccessTokenFormat` for the access token, and create a refresh token with `RefreshTokenProvider`.